# Add elements to a textfile using a dictionary

Tags: python

Is there a shorter way to write this code or parts of it and where can i inculde some try and excepts for validation

```
   People={"Dan":22,
            "Matt":54,
            "Harry":78,
            "Bob":91}

schoice=input('Enter existing name: ')
while schoice not in People:
    schoice=input('Invalid entry name is non existant, Enter a chosen name: ')
if schoice in People:
    getscore=People[schoice]
    if getscore<50:
        presents=[]
        for x in range(2):
            present=input('Enter present ' +str(x+1))
            while present == '':
                present = input('Invalid. Try again: ')
            presents.append(present)
    if getscore>=100:
        presents=[]
        for x in range (8):
            present=input('Enter present ' +str(x+1))
            while present == '':
                present = input('Invalid. Try again: ')
            presents.append(present)
    if getscore>=50 and getscore <100:
        presents = []
        for x in range (5):
            present=input('Enter present ' +str(x+1))
            while present == '':
                present = input('Invalid. Try again: ')
            presents.append(present)
File=open("presfile.txt",'a')
File.write(schoice)
File.write(str(presents)+'\n')
File.close()
```

Comment: Is `People` meant to be indented so much? As currently this isn't runnable.

Answer (score 3):

## [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

There are quite a number of style-related "errors" in the code. Try to adhere to the Python PEP8 style guide. Here are a few key points for this particular case:

- Variables and functions are written in snake_case, classes PascalCase and constants (if any) are written fully in UPPERCASE.
- Use a single space around operators, assignments, comparisons, etc.
- Use proper indentation (e.g. at `People`)
- Use descriptive variable names.

Also use some whitespace here and there to make it more readable.

Some examples from the code:

> `people` instead of `People`
>
> `get_score` instead of `getscore`. Also `get_score` seems more like a function name rather than a variable name. Perhaps just use `score` as this is the actual value of the variable.
>
> `if get_score >= 100` instead of `if getscore>=100`
>
> `file = open('presfile.txt', 'a')` instead of `File=open("presfile.txt",'a')
>
> `chosen_name` instead of `schoice`. Perhaps `person` or `chosen_person` is even better, as this gets a value from `People`.

---

#### Use functions

Functions make the code more readable and splits up the responsibility of the code in smaller, reusable code. This also makes it a lot easier to test the application with for instance `unittest`. Once divided into functions, the code can easily be imported into another project, if need be.

---

You are doubly checking if `schoice` is in `People`

```py
while schoice not in People:
    schoice=input('Invalid entry name is non existant, Enter a chosen name: ')
if schoice in People:
    getscore=People[schoice]
```

Once the `if` is reached, it is already certain that `schoice` is in `People`, otherwise the `while` loop would not be broken.

The code

```py
presents = []
for x in range (5):
    present=input('Enter present ' +str(x+1))
    while present == '':
        present = input('Invalid. Try again: ')
    presents.append(present)
```

is repeated 3 times only with a different range. Put it in a separate function. See also: [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

```py
def get_presents(amount):
    """Return a list of presents equal in size to the given amount"""
    presents = []
    for x in range(amount):
        while True:
            present = input('Enter present #{}: '.format(x+1))
            if present:
                presents.append(present)
                break
            else:
                print('Invalid present, try again.')
    return presents
```

Now you can call this function with the amount of expected presents and it will return the list of presents: `get_presents(5)`

The `if` checks

```py
if score < 50:
    ...
if score >= 100:
    ...
if score >= 50 and score < 100
# can also be written as 50 <= score < 100
    ...
```

has the code check get_score up to three times. This is not particularly a performance issue in this case, but could also be written as:

```py
if score < 50:
    ...
elif score >= 100:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Use `with` to open the file:

```py
with open('presfile.txt', 'a') as presfile:
    presfile.write(chosen_person)
    presfile.write(str(presents) + '\n')
```

This ensures that the file is always closed. See also [`file.close`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.close) and [this answer about `with`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369526/what-is-the-python-keyword-with-used-for#11783672)

---

The code:

```py
def get_presents(amount):
    """Return a list of presents equal in size to the given amount"""
    presents = []
    for x in range(amount):
        while True:
            present = input('Enter present #{}: '.format(x+1))
            if present:
                presents.append(present)
                break
            else:
                print('Invalid present, try again.')
    return presents


def get_presents_for_person():
    """Description of function."""
    people = {
        "Dan": 22,
        "Matt": 54,
        "Harry": 78,
        "Bob": 91,
    }

    chosen_person = input('Enter existing name: ')
    while chosen_person not in people:
        chosen_person = input('The chosen name does not exist. '
                              'Please enter an existing name: ')

    score = people[chosen_person]
    presents = []

    if score < 50:
        presents = get_presents(2)
    elif score >= 100:
        presents = get_presents(8)
    else:
        presents = get_presents(5)

    return chosen_person, presents


if __name__ == '__main__':
    chosen_person, presents = get_presents_for_person()

    with open('presfile.txt', 'a') as presfile:
        presfile.write(chosen_person)
        presfile.write(str(presents) + '\n')
```

---

#### What's next?

You could make the values of `People` an actual class. This allows you to further expand upon it if necessary in the future. For example something like:

```py
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, score):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score
```